# MySQL denied access in java, workbench access granted

Tags: java, mysql

I've been using java on a computer (lets call it PC1) to connect to a database on a server, and until recently it was working with no errors.

By working, I mean I could connect to the server using java on PC1, and access the info I needed from the tables using select statements.

The only changes that have been made are the ip addresses on PC1 and the server. 
After changing the IP addresses, I then updated the grant table in mysql, and yet, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'robot'@'aa-PC' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at WriteToMySql.connection1(WriteToMySql.java:26)
at WriteToMySql.main(WriteToMySql.java:259)
```

The strange part however, is that I am able to connect to the server's database using the mySQL workbench and access all data on them.

here's the java code:

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://PC1IPAdress:3306/users";
String user= "robot";
String password="mypassword";

    public void connect() 
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("worked"); //this gets printed

        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
        System.out.println("works"); // this does not get printed due to error
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

note: "users" is the name of the database

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT:
for testing purposes I tried turning off the firewall, but it did not help.

Comment: try `telnet host 3306` and check if it allows remote access

Comment: yep, remote access is allowed

Comment: then your code should work fine

Comment: Which is why my mind is boggled. What really confuses me is that I am able to connect via SQL workbench, but not through java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an error in the code sample - it connects to PC1IPAddress when you mention that PC1 should be connecting to a server earlier in the post. Just want to make sure before we continue that it was a typo, as otherwise PC1 would be connecting to itself.

If you have administrative access to the server, connect to MySQL as root and use this query to show configured users and ensure the host field is correct: `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='robot';`

If the above checks out, I would suggest looking into Windows user authentication. The fact that MySQL returned the Windows computer name ('aa-PC') and not its IP address seems to indicate it may be attempting to authenticate using Windows domain credentials: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

If you change the ip address of the client (PC1) make sure that you updated the host field as well when granting new rights to user "robot". Check the table "db", "user" and "host".